# Running a MATLAB Script on an already running MATLAB Session

Tags: php, bash, matlab

I am using a PHP server at the back end and a basic web page which asks the user to upload an image. This image is used as an input to a MATLAB script to be executed on the server side.

What I need is something like a MATLAB session(not clear on that word) that is already running on the server side which runs the MATLAB script. I know about the command: `"matlab -nodesktop -nojvm"` which can be used but the point is that I don't wish to invoke MATLAB again and again, rather, just execute the MATLAB script on the running MATLAB instance whenever a user uploads an image, get the output(necessary).

There are some constraints:
1. OS -> Ubuntu
2. Can't use python engine.

Answer (score 2):

There exist multiple interfaces to control matlab. Probably best choice for this case is [matlabcontrol](https://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/) or the matlab engine for python (which you can't use for some reason). On windows a third alternative would be com.

Besides controlling the matlab process, you could implement an application in matlab which recieves the data, processes it and sends it back. I solved a similar problem using [apache xmlrpc](https://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/) in matlab.

There are also some submissions on matlab file exchange, directly providing a matlab console [via web](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29027-web-server)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Matlab Control worked for me. It is a much better option because python engine works only with 2013 - present versions of MATLAB

Answer (score 2):

You could write Matlab code to check the upload folder for new images regularly. Process new images and then move the processed images to an archive folder.

To check for new files use `dir` command

```
FILES = dir(['path/to/upload/folder/*.PNG']);
```

Replace PNG extension with that of your image files.

To move files use `movefile` command

```
movefile('path/to/upload/folder/Filename.PNG', 'path/to/archive/folder/', 'f')
```

To run the Matlab script from terminal and keep it running in the background

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -r "cd /path/to/matlab/code; MatlabScript" ; < ctrl > Z; bg; disown -h %1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an API for C++ where you call the Matlab engine using engOpen.  This will open Matlab and leave it running until you close it.  Then your C++ program can wait and listen for the image to process.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-c-and-fortran-programs.html

Another option is to compile the Matlab script as a standalone executable.  Hard code the input image name and output and let PHP handle moving around the inputs and outputs.  All the server needs to do is call the executable.  It takes about 5 seconds to start the Matlab runtime each time.